# Why are some of our badges in Portuguese?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I've noticed today that **some of our badges have names and their description in Portuguese**. This isn't affecting [SO](http://stackoverflow.com) or [WorldBuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com).

I am not in Spain/Portugal/Brazil; I am in the United Kingdom and my language is set to English (UK).

This only affects badges on the main site, not on Meta.

## Affected Badges

The following BRONZE and SILVER types of badges are affected:

- question score badges ([Nice Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/46/nice-question)/[Good Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/good-question))
- question views badges ([Popular Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/48/popular-question)/[Notable Question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/47/notable-question))
- answer score badges ([Nice Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/45/nice-answer)/[Good Answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/good-answer))

Also, the following other badges, gold and silver, are affected:

- [Populist](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/49/populist)
- [Fanatic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/fanatic)
- [Sportsmanship](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/58/sportsmanship)

## Screenshots

From the badge list:

[image: Portuguese labels for question score/views badges]

[A list of all badges can be found here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges).

Comment: For the record, I see these in English as usual (US English, Windows 7, Chrome latest)

Comment: @Geobits Thanks. It can't possibly be related to my client (or so I think), because SO and Meta are fine

Comment: I confirm the bug, and I confirm that it's Portuguese.

Comment: I have a faint suspicion that this is something to do with [Portuguese SO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @professorfish This is totally a publicity stunt.

Comment: Possibly related meta.se post? [Non-english Badge Notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234589/212780)

Comment: @Geobits I've posted a comment on that to get some attention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in build `2014.10.1.1906`.